# Prove the value of the $k$th symmetric sum via induction

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

Define the $k$th **symmetric sum** of a polynomial with $n$ roots as the sum of all products formed by multiplying $k$ of the roots. For example, if the $3$ roots of $f(x)$ were $1,2,$ and $3$, the $2$nd symmetric sum of that polynomial would be $$1\times2+1\times3+2\times3=11$$

Prove by induction that the $k$th symmetric sum is $$(-1)^ka_{n-k}/a_n$$

I know that given a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0,$ the sum of its roots is $\frac{-a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ and the product of its roots is $\frac{-a_0}{a_n}$, and thus I can do the base case. I don't know how to continue, however.

Answer (score 1):

What you are refering are known as [Vieta's Fromulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

It can be proven by noticing that we have:

$$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 = f(x) = a_n(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) \cdots (x-\alpha_n)$$

where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $f$. Now expland the right side and compare the coefficients.

---

If you insist on having an inductional proof, the induction can be done on the degree of the polynomial. The base case is trivial and assume it's true for $\text{deg } f = n-1$. Then we have that:

$$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 = f(x) = a_n(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) \cdots (x-\alpha_n) = a_nf_{n-1}(x)(x- \alpha_n)$$

If $f_{n-1}(x) = x^{n-1} + b_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \cdots b_0$ then we have that $k$-th symmetric sum of $f$ is the sum of the $k$-th symmetric sum of $f_{n-1}$ and the $(k-1)$-th symmetric sum of $f_{n-1}$ times $\alpha_n$. Using the induction hypothesis we would be able to make the conclusion.